# Não consigo importar temas no wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Eu estou tentando instalar um tema no Wordpress, mas aparece esse erro:

> ( Warning: POST Content-Length of 46588481 bytes exceeds the limit of
>   8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0 )

Obrigado

Comment: Você tem que aumentar o limite do POST do php.ini

Answer (score 3):

Se usa xampp navegue até a pasta:

> C:\xampp\php\php.ini

Procura a linha:

```
post_max_size=8M
```

Muda para:

```
post_max_size=50M
```

Ou tamanho que queira. Reinicie o serviço do apache e mysql.

Para linux veja esse tutorial:

http://nabeto.blogspot.com.br/2010/10/aumentando-o-limite-de-upload-de-dados.html